# How to access the JNDI namespace defined in the Websphere 7.0 from outside of the container?

Tags: java, jndi, websphere-7

I am tring to lookup the resource defined on the Websphere aplication server 7.0 from the out side of the Container with using the iiop protocol as below:

Java code for (RMI client)Test.jar:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
Hashtable<Object, Object> properties = new Hashtable<Object, Object>();
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, 
        "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory"); 
           properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://localhost:2809"); 
InitialContext intCt;
try {
       InitialContext initCtx = new InitialContext(properties);
       Object obj = intCt.lookup(JNDI_NAME);
     }catch (NamingException namingE) {
            System.out.println("Naming Exception occurred :");
            namingE.printStackTrace();
        }   
}
```

Cmmand file to call the Test.jar:

```
set appClassPath=C:\WebSphere\AppServer7.0\deploytool\itp\plugins\com.ibm.websphere.v7_7.0.1.v20090422_1423\wasJars\naming.jar;C:\WebSphere\AppServer7.0\deploytool\itp\plugins\com.ibm.websphere.v7_7.0.1.v20090422_1423\wasJars\namingclient.jar;C:\WebSphere\AppServer7.0\properties;C:\Batch\CommandFiles\JobServer\Test.jar

C:\WebSphere\AppServer7.0\java\jre\bin\java -jar -cp "%appClassPath%" C:\Batch\CommandFiles\JobServer\Test.jar %Parameters%
```

NOTE : Please not that I am runnig the client on my local machin and bootstrap host is : localhost and the port is 2809.

At the time of running the Test.jar code form the command file I am getting the following error:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Failed to create InitialContext using factory specified in hashtable {java.naming.provider.url=iiop://localhost:2809, java.naming.factory.initial=com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory} [Root exception is java.lang.NullPointerException]
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:243)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.initializeDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:327)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:357)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.internalInit(InitialContext.java:295)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.(InitialContext.java:212)
    at com.uuic.ets.rmi.server.client.Client.main(Client.java:130)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:235)
    ... 5 more
```

I have no idea that why this code is not able to instantiat the `InitialContext(Hashmap env)`. This same code is running in Websphere application server version 5.1 but having problem in Websphere application server version 7.0.

Answer (score 2):

Using JARs from WAS_HOME/deploytool for the classpath is not supported.  Try using the documented [EJB thinclient](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/tcli_ejbthinclient.html) with WAS_HOME/runtimes/com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_7.0.0.jar.

Comment: Where can I find IIOP port and hostname? somewhere on WAS8 Admin console?

Comment: @GovindaSakhare Presumably, yes, but I have not used WAS in several years.  If you can't find it, I recommend starting a new question rather than commenting on a 7-year-old answer.